# Creating a PowerShell module from files

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have seen this question here but there not working for me.

I currently have taken apart a psm1 file with 200 functions and separated them into individual files.

Functions are separated into public and private functions

```
\\nasShare\dbasupport\Powershell\Modules\SQLdbatools\SQLdbatools\public
\\nasShare\dbasupport\Powershell\Modules\SQLdbatools\SQLdbatools\private
```

This is what my new SQLdbatools.psm1 file looks like

```
#Get public and private function definition files.
    $Public  = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Public\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
    $Private = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Private\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )

#Dot source the files
    Foreach($import in @($Public + $Private))
    {
        Try
        {
            . $import.fullname
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.fullname): $_"
        }
    }


Export-ModuleMember -Function $Public.Basename
```

But the Export-ModuleMember gives me an error that command cant be run from psm1 file

Contents of SQLdbatools.ps1xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>Default</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>SQLdbatools.Question</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>48</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>12</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>5</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Owner</Label>
                        <Width>15</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Tags</Label>
                        <Width>20</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <Wrap />
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Title</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Answer_Count</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Score</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.Owner.display_name</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>($_.Tags | Sort-Object) -Join ', '</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
        <View>
            <Name>Default</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>SQLdbatools.Answer</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>50</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Owner</Label>
                        <Width>20</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>5</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>11</Width>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <Wrap />
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Share_Link</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.Owner.display_name</ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Score</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Is_Accepted</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

contents of my SQLdbatools.psd1 file

```
@{
# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'SQLdbatools.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '1.0.0'
   
# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
FormatsToProcess = 'SQLdbatools.Format.ps1xml'


# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = '*'

# Cmdlets to export from this module
CmdletsToExport = '*'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'

}
```

I have ran the SQLdbatools.psm1 without

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function $Public.Basename
```

it will not fail but the ps1 files don't load. Is there something wrong in the code or am I not setting this Module up correctly.

Error when trying to import module
Import-Module SQLdbatools

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'SQLdbatools' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module SQLdbatools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SQLdbatools:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: The `Export-ModuleMember` cmdlet works fine for me within the **.psm1** file, and your code works as expected as long as your filenames are in the expected format (e.g., if I want to export a function called `Get-ExampleFunction`, in the public directory I'd need to call the file `Get-ExampleFunction.ps1`. Additionally, when importing the module, instead of importing with `Import-Module SQLdbatools`, I'm importing with `Import-Module .\SQLdbatools` so that PowerShell knows to load from the current folder)

Comment: Either use the full path to the module definition file (eg: C:\PATH_TO\SQLdbatools.psd1) or make sure it is at one of the location defined in `$env:PSModulePath` if you want to import by name.

Comment: yes. I needed to Import-module .\SQLdbatools and misspelled the ps1xml file. Once I fixed that it worked